# Where is the Conversion Namespace in Windows Store Apps

Tags: .net, namespaces, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am trying to write my first `Windows Store App` and am using some code from an old project.  I am developing on a *Windows 8.1 Pro* machine with *Visual Studio 2013 Express*.

I have no idea what people are calling the version of .NET I'm targeting and therefore, cannot google my questions efficiently.  I don't even know what version of .NET I'm targeting.  It is not like WPF where you select it.

My old code references `CTypeDynamic` which was in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Conversion` namespace.

Where would I find a function that does what `CTypeDynamic` did?

Comment: Are you using VB or C#?

Comment: VB.NET, but C# would work also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what CTypeDynamic does then [System.Convert.ChangeType(Object, Type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx) looks like the equivalent and is available in the [.NET for Windows Runtime apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230232.aspx)

Comment: Woohoo!  Thank you for answering the question and pointing me to the .NET documentation.  I will accept your answer after I get the other parts of the code working and can test it satisfactorily.

Comment: For reference: another google-able term I found people using for _.NET for Windows Runtime apps_ is **WinRT**.